# LocalBroadcastManager not receiving messages correctly

Tags: java, android, localbroadcastmanager

I have a, what I thought was a, simple task. I have a list of achievements in a recyclerView in my MainActivity. Clicking on one of the achievements launches the AchievementDetailActivity. You do an action in the AchievementDetailActivity and it completes the achievement. When that happens, I need the thumbnail on the MainActivity to be the achievement icon and not the locked icon. What I thought was I could just use the LocalBroadcastManager to send and receive messages from one activity to another, but that isn't working. From everything I have read you are supposed to unregister the listener in your activity onPause and onStop lifecycle methods, however, if you unregister the listener in the onPause of MainActivity, it gets unregistered when the AchievementDetailActivity starts and nothing gets delivered to the MainActivity. I don't understand how you can use LocalBroadCastManager with receivers to send information between activities when they get unregistered as soon as you start a new activity. The following example shows it unregisters as soon as the second activity is started, so the first activity will never get the broadcast...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  public static final String ACTION = "update";

  private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MAIN ACTIVITY", "RECEIVED EVENT");
    }
  }
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver), new IntentFilter(ACTION));
  }

  public void onPause() {
    Log.d("MAIN ACTIVITY", "REMOVING LISTENER");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  }
  //.. The rest of MainActivity
}

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //initialize view and such
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.ACTION);
        intent.putExtra("Something", "somewhere");
        manager.sendBroadcast(intent);
      }
    )};
  }
```

If you run the above, obviously with the buttons and such, you will get a message that shows it unregisters the listener as soon as SecondActivity starts and the MainActivity will never get the message it is supposed to get when you click a button on the second activity.

Is there a way to send information from activity to activity, or because of the lifecycle events is that not possible? Everything I read said LocalBroadcastManager was the right way to do it, but it gets unregistered so, how can it? Please help, this is driving me nuts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a great idea to use `LocalBroadcastReceiver` for this purpose. Use `startActivityForResult` instead. Follow this  [Official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) for implementation details.

The reason its not wokring is:

You are registering the receiver in `onStart` and unregistering it in `onPause()`. When your second activity is shown, `onPause ()` will be called as a result the `BroadcastReceiver` is unregistered.

Its not a great idea to keep it registered since it would lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your `LocalBroadcastManager` to fetch results, do not `unregister` in `onPause`, in which case must to `unregister` in `onDestroy()`.

If you `startAvtivity` only to fetch some results, it is a good way to `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: The only problem is I am not specifically looking for a result from the activity. The user can either go into the detail view and look at it, then go back to the main activity with the actionbar back button, or they can complete the challenge, then go back with the actionbar back button. So I didn't think start activity for result applied, since it was only an option to do the challenge.

Comment: You can consider keeping the `LocalBroadcastManager` registered until `onDestroy()` is called.